# Why can't I edit firewall settings on my Netgear router?

Tags: router, firewall

My router is the Netgear WNR854T or firmware 1.4.38. I am trying to access the firewall configuration settings, but the link to get there isn't showing up.

This is what I see:

[image]

As you can see, the "Firewall Rules" box that is supposed to appear doesn't. Why isn't it there, and how do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They either screwed up when the wrote that firmware update and left out that menu item (generally unlikely, but you never know), or they simply took it out for some reason.

The only way to get it back will be to go to a previous firmware revision, and wait for the next update to see if it has been restored.

http://support.netgear.com/app/products/model/a_id/2619

Comment: @awesomeguy Was it there previously? If not, it is just not an option. I figured it was there, but you comment make me think it is not an option. Why did you say "is supposed to appear (but) doesn't"?

Comment: @awesomeguy I looked at the manual, and there is no menu that is similar. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, every guide that I have seen to edit the firewall settings for Netgear routers has told me to look for "Firewall Rules" under "Content Filtering". However, I can't see it on my router in this case.

Comment: This is a screenshot of what I think I am supposed to see: http://www.lowercall.com/netgear/images/netgear8.gif

Comment: OK, I would go back to the latest firmware, and then read the manual: ftp://downloads.netgear.com/files/WNR854T_RM_20Apr06.pdf Chapter 3 is entitled "Content filtering". You really can't use generalities like that...sometimes they help, but sometimes, not. If all this helped you, I would ask that you upvote and check the answer as marked.

Comment: The pics you are posting are not for your router...at least per the manual. They can vary, and I have seen the screens in your manual, so they are also common.

Comment: I guess it's a hardware problem... maybe I just can't do it... whatever.

Comment: @KCotreau let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/582/discussion-between-awesomeguy-and-kcotreau)

Comment: They simply changed what you are expecting. I would read chapter 3, and see what it says. If you tell me exactly what you are trying to do, I might be able to tell you how.